# Binary adder implemented in Rust

Tags: rust

I implemented a ripple carry adder in Rust. The function takes and outputs strings of `1`s and `0`s.

How can I improve this according to better Rust coding practises and API design, and make it more robust?

```rs
struct SumCarry {
    sum: char,
    carry: char
}

fn add_bits(left: char, right: char, carry_in: char) -> SumCarry {
    match (left, right, carry_in) {
        ('0', '0', '0') => SumCarry { sum: '0', carry: '0' },
        ('0', '1', '0') => SumCarry { sum: '1', carry: '0' },
        ('1', '0', '0') => SumCarry { sum: '1', carry: '0' },
        ('1', '1', '0') => SumCarry { sum: '0', carry: '1' },
        ('0', '0', '1') => SumCarry { sum: '1', carry: '0' },
        ('0', '1', '1') => SumCarry { sum: '0', carry: '1' },
        ('1', '0', '1') => SumCarry { sum: '0', carry: '1' },
        ('1', '1', '1') => SumCarry { sum: '1', carry: '1' },
        _ => panic!()
    }
}

fn zip_longest<IntoIter, Item>(left: IntoIter, right: IntoIter, default: Item) -> impl Iterator<Item = (Item, Item)>
where
    Item: Clone,
    IntoIter: IntoIterator<Item = Item>
{
    let mut left_iter = left.into_iter();
    let mut right_iter = right.into_iter();
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        match (left_iter.next(), right_iter.next()) {
            (Some(l), Some(r)) => Some((l, r)),
            (Some(l), None) => Some((l, default.clone())),
            (None, Some(r)) => Some((default.clone(), r)),
            (None, None) => None
        }
    })
}

pub fn ripple_carry_adder(left: &str, right: &str) -> String {
    let mut carry_in = '0';
    let mut result = String::new();
    for (l, r) in zip_longest(left.chars().rev(), right.chars().rev(), '0') {
        let SumCarry { sum, carry: carry_out } = add_bits(l, r, carry_in);
        result.insert(0, sum);
        carry_in = carry_out;
    }
    if carry_in == '1' {
        result.insert(0, carry_in);
    }
    result
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", ripple_carry_adder("101", "1"));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Because you're only working with ascii `0` and `1` you could use bytes instead of characters everywhere, it saves 3 bytes for every time a `char` would be there but arguably it makes the literals a lot less readable:

```rust
struct SumCarry {
    sum: u8,
    carry: u8,
}
```

---

In this `match` several patterns have the same outcome, you can join them using `|`

```rust
fn add_bits(left: u8, right: u8, carry_in: u8) -> SumCarry {
    match (left, right, carry_in) {
        (b'0', b'0', b'0') => SumCarry { sum: b'0', carry: b'0', },

        (b'0', b'1', b'0') | (b'1', b'0', b'0') | (b'0', b'0', b'1') => SumCarry {
            sum: b'1',
            carry: b'0',
        },

        (b'1', b'1', b'0') | (b'0', b'1', b'1') | (b'1', b'0', b'1') => SumCarry {
            sum: b'0',
            carry: b'1',
        },

        (b'1', b'1', b'1') => SumCarry { sum: b'1', carry: b'1', },
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

---

Since `zip_longest` is already very specialized to your situation might as well fix item to `char`/`u8` and drop the `default`

```rust
fn zip_longest<IntoIter>(left: IntoIter, right: IntoIter) -> impl Iterator<Item = (u8, u8)>
where
    IntoIter: IntoIterator<Item = u8>
{
    const DEFAULT: u8 = b'0';
    let mut left_iter = left.into_iter();
    let mut right_iter = right.into_iter();
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        match (left_iter.next(), right_iter.next()) {
            (Some(l), Some(r)) => Some((l, r)),
            (Some(l), None) => Some((l, DEFAULT)),
            (None, Some(r)) => Some((DEFAULT, r)),
            (None, None) => None
        }
    })
}
```

Alternatively you could make it a lot more general by simply not binding both iterators to be of the same type:

```rust
fn zip_longest<L, R, Item>(left: L, right: R, default: Item) -> impl Iterator<Item = (Item, Item)>
where
    Item: Clone,
    L: IntoIterator<Item = Item>,
    R: IntoIterator<Item = Item>,
{
    let mut left_iter = left.into_iter();
    let mut right_iter = right.into_iter();
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        match (left_iter.next(), right_iter.next()) {
            (Some(l), Some(r)) => Some((l, r)),
            (Some(l), None) => Some((l, default.clone())),
            (None, Some(r)) => Some((default.clone(), r)),
            (None, None) => None
        }
    })
}
```

---

Inserting at the beginning of a `String` means that all characters have to be copied over it is O(n), that means that your `ripple_carry_adder` is accidentially O(n<sup>2</sup>) you should prefer reversing the string once instead.

```rust
pub fn ripple_carry_adder(left: &str, right: &str) -> String {
    let mut carry_in = b'0';
    let mut result = String::new();
    for (l, r) in zip_longest(left.bytes().rev(), right.bytes().rev()) {
        let sum;
        SumCarry {
            sum,
            carry: carry_in,
        } = add_bits(l, r, carry_in);
        result.push(sum as char);
    }
    if carry_in == b'1' {
        result.push(carry_in as char);
    }
    result.chars().rev().collect()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful. I actually tried to make a general `zip_longest`. What about it currently makes it specific?

Comment: It requires both `left` and `right` to be of the same type, you couldn't for example pass in one forward and one reversed iterator over the same collection.

Comment: The `match` could be entirely replaced with the boolean expressions for the output bits: it's a full adder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder), so `sum = left ^ right ^ carry_in;` and `carry_out = ((left ^ right)&carry_in) | (left & right);`.  Or more simply, use the low 2 bits of a u8 for integer addition and extract them: `sum = a+b+carry_in;` `carry_out = sum >> 1;` (bit #1) `sum &= 1;` (bit #0).  When doing extended / arbitrary precision integer math, you can use fixed-width addition as a building block, @theonlygusti.  Normally 32 or 64-bit chunks!

Comment: In languages like C where you don't have convenient access to the carry-out of a full-width addition, or the ability to feed it a carry-in, you might do like Python and use 30-bit chunks in 32-bit integers, so there's room for adding integers and having the carry-out in the `uint32_t`.  But in languages like Rust that are better at this, you'd use `let (sum, carry_out) = left.carrying_add(right, carry_in)` - https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.carrying_add (carrying_add is a new API.)

Comment: If you're manually simulating a ripple-carry adder internals, you can keep it simple and do each bit separately, or derive what the carry-in must have been for each bit from the sum and the two inputs, and use that to calculate the carry-out.  So you can get 64 sum bits and 64 carry-out bits stored in two `u64`s, calculated with only one `adc` and a few boolean operations and maybe a shift, @theonlygusti.  That's a very different design than what you went for, so IDK if I should post that as a code-review answer, especially without taking the time to actually write it in Rust.

Answer (score 4):

I’ll start with the really minor stuff.

### Reconsider Names Like `l`

It’s easily confused with the numeral `1`, or more rarely `I`, and if you don’t have `l` and `r` on the same screen, it can be very hard to guess what either one is an abbreviation for.

### You Can Clean up `zip_longest` a Bit

The basic approach here is sound.  However, what you actually want to do is

- Take two generic iterators (so you can pass in reversed or mapped iterators)
- Whose item types have default values, from the `std::default::Default` trait
- Pad the shorter sequence with default values (without cloning, although this is harmless for built-in types)
- Zip to an iterator over pairs
- And hand along the result to the chain

That gives you a function that you might plausibly re-use in another app.  It’s very close to what you wrote:

```rust
fn zip_pad<IterA, IterB>(mut left_it: IterA, mut right_it: IterB) ->
    impl Iterator<Item = (IterA::Item, IterB::Item)>
where
    IterA: Iterator,
    IterB: Iterator,
    IterA::Item: Default,
    IterB::Item: Default
{
    return std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        match (left_it.next(), right_it.next()) {
            (None, None)              => None,
            (Some(left), None)        => Some ((left, IterB::Item::default())),
            (None, Some(right))       => Some((IterA::Item::default(), right)),
            (Some(left), Some(right)) => Some((left, right))
        }
    })
}
```

The core logic is similar, but it drops `IntoIterator`, the user-supplied default value, and the separate `Item` type parameter (If that was on purpose, you might want a `type` alias), and is more flexible about accepting two different types of iterator.

**Update:** You’ve explained your reasoning in the comments, and it makes sense. Sometimes you want to pad with different elements (zero digits, spaces, null bytes).  In that case, I’d still clean up the associated types and traits a bit, but your approach better suits what you wanted and mine is more of a special case.

### Now Some Significant Advice

Iterate Over the Bytes of the String, not the Codepoints

In Rust, a `String` is stored in UTF-8.  Calling `String::chars` will give you an iterator of 32-bit Unicode codepoints.  You can iterate forward or in reverse, but this is inefficient, compared to iterating over a `Vec`, because UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding.  You must count the bytes representing each Unicode codepoint and convert it to 32-bit UCS-4.

If you convert the string into an iterator of bytes, each element is a fixed width and the optimizer can go to town.  In particular, LLVM will now prrform tail-call elimination and inline all the functions.

### Use `bool` for Internal Computation

The main convenience of this for you is that your matches can be exhaustive without needing to throw in a default clause (which spoils the very nice feature of warning you when you write a non-exhaustive pattern).  This also saves you from needing to do any runtime checks for valid `char` values after the initial conversion, and the compiler can pack them more efficiently than `char`—which, remember, is not a single byte in Rust, nor is a string stored as an array of `char`.

But it generates better code, too.

Here are some partial listings of what you get when running `zip_longest` on `char` iterators.  An excerpt of the code to check for `None` versus `Some(l)` and `Some(r)`:

```
.LBB9_17:
        mov     rbx, r15
        cmp     ecx, 1114112
        jne     .LBB9_23
        jmp     .LBB9_46
.LBB9_11:
        movzx   edx, byte ptr [rbx - 1]
        test    dl, dl
        js      .LBB9_14
        dec     rbx
        cmp     ecx, 1114112
        jne     .LBB9_22
.LBB9_13:
        cmp     edx, 1114112
        jne     .LBB9_30
        jmp     .LBB9_46
```

There are at least six comparisons of a register to `1114112`, AKA `0x110000`, the first number that is not a valid Unicode codepoint and the binary representation of `None` for `Option<char>`.

This then calls `carry_bits`.  An excerpt of the code for the `match` expression in that function:

```
.LBB9_24:
        cmp     ecx, 48
        je      .LBB9_30
        cmp     ecx, 49
        jne     .LBB9_45
        cmp     edx, 49
        je      .LBB9_40
        cmp     edx, 48
        jne     .LBB9_49
        mov     cl, 49
        cmp     eax, 48
        jne     .LBB9_33
        jmp     .LBB9_39
.LBB9_30:
        cmp     edx, 48
        je      .LBB9_35
        cmp     edx, 49
        jne     .LBB9_49
        mov     cl, 49
        cmp     eax, 48
        je      .LBB9_39
.LBB9_33:
        cmp     eax, 49
        jne     .LBB9_49
        mov     cl, 48
        mov     ebp, 49
        jmp     .LBB9_43
.LBB9_35:
        mov     cl, 48
        cmp     eax, 48
        je      .LBB9_39
        cmp     eax, 49
        jne     .LBB9_49
        mov     cl, 49
        mov     ebp, 48
        jmp     .LBB9_43
.LBB9_39:
        mov     ebp, eax
```

ASCII 48 is `'0'` and ASCII 49 is `'1'`, so we can see that the program is doing a series of nested conditional branches.  Unlike the previous set of conditional branches, which at least only switch to returning `None` once, these are not predictable.  This means they will incur [hefty branch misprediction penalties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) on a modern CPU.

Calling the `bool` overload of `zip_pad` changes the generated code for one path through the same functions, adding two digits, to:

```
.LBB6_12:
        dec     qword ptr [rsp]
        cmp     al, 2
        jne     .LBB6_7
```

```
.LBB6_7:
        test    al, al
        setne   bl
        test    cl, cl
        setne   al
        mov     r14d, eax
        and     r14b, bl
        xor     bl, al
```

In this case, `al` holds an `Option<bool>`, whose binary representation is either 0 for `Some(false)`, 1 for `Some(true)` or 2 for `None`.  If we call the Boolean value initially in `al`, *a*, and the value initially in `cl`, *c*, we see that, when *a* is not `None`, the program jumps to a branch that sets the next digit to *a* ⊕ *c* and the carry-out to *a* ∧ *c*.

The generated code for the more complex cases is:

```
.LBB6_35:
        dec     rdi
        cmp     al, 2
        jne     .LBB6_26
        test    r14b, r14b
        setne   bl
        jmp     .LBB6_37
.LBB6_25:
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     rdi, rsi
.LBB6_26:
        test    r14b, r14b
        setne   bl
        test    dl, dl
        setne   r12b
        test    al, al
        je      .LBB6_37
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rdi
        test    dl, dl
        setne   al
        test    r14b, r14b
        setne   r12b
        or      dl, r14b
        setne   r14b
        xor     r12b, al
        xor     r12b, 1
        mov     r15b, 3
        lea     rbx, [rbp + 1]
        cmp     rbx, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        jne     .LBB6_41
        jmp     .LBB6_42
.LBB6_37:
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rdi
        mov     r14d, r12d
        and     r14b, bl
        xor     r12b, bl
        mov     r15b, 3
        lea     rbx, [rbp + 1]
        cmp     rbx, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        jne     .LBB6_41
```

Not only are these shorter instructions, they are branchless, inline and use bitwise register instructions.  You also see that iterating over the byte iterator in reverse order, but not the `String::chars()` iterator, is as simple as decrementing a pointer by one byte.

### You Can Generate the (Reversed) Output as an Iterator

It’s more efficient to do this and `.collect()` the results into a `Vec` than to `insert` within a loop, because each insertion must check the amount of space available and the current end of the vector, and resize if necessary.

When you `.collect()` a standard-library iterator, it comes with a size hint that lets the implementation create the `Vec` with approximately the right size buffer and fill it up to the amount of memory it reserved without checking again.

The code is very similar to the very nice code you wrote for `zip_longest`, which comes out fine when you call it with `.bytes().rev().map(to_bool)` instead of `.chars().rev()`.

```rust
    let mut reverse_zip = zip_pad(a_rev, b_rev).peekable();
    let mut carry = false;

    let mut sum : Vec<u8> = std::iter::from_fn(move|| {
        match (reverse_zip.peek(), carry) {
            (None, false) => None,
            (None, true) => {
                carry = false;
                Some(true)
            }
            (Some(&(a, b)), carry_in) => {
                let (digit, carry_out) = add_bits(a, b, carry_in);
                carry = carry_out;
                reverse_zip.next();
                Some(digit)
            }
        }
    }).map(to_utf8)
      .collect();
```

There are a couple of wrinkles here: if there is a carry out of the final digit, we need to return one **more** digit of output than there were pairs of input digits.  If not for that, I could much more simply have used `Iterator::scan`.  Trying to cheat by not returning `None` on the last item of input causes an internal panic.

To work around that, I make the zipped iterator `.peekable()`, and then `.peek()` ahead to decide what to do.  If we’re on the last input item and there is no carry, I return the leading `1`, clear the carry-in, and **don’t** advance the input iterator.  That causes the next iteration to hit the terminating case, safely.

Although it’s at odds with what is otherwise similar to functional programming, this kind of closure in Rust requires mutable external state.

You’ll also observe that this generates the output bytes in the same order as `reverse_zip`, that is, backwards.

### Add from Right to Left, then Reverse, to Avoid Array-Shifting

I see that @cafce25 beat me to this one, but it’s important advice.  Whenever you insert at the front of a `String`, the entire string has to be shifted one character to the right, whenever you add a digit.  This takes O(N²) time in all.  You want to get that down to O(N).  Not only that, but a `char` in Rust is not an alias for byte like in C; it is a Unicode codepoint that must be converted from and two UTF-8 whenever it is extracted from and inserted into a `String`.

### Remove Unnecessary Copies

Once you have generated the digits of output into a sequence of `bool`, you can convert it to ASCII digits by mapping a helper function:

```rust
    const fn to_utf8(d: bool) -> u8 {
        match d {
            false => '0' as u8,
            true  => '1' as u8
        }
    }
```

This compiles to next-to-no overhead: an inline `add r8, 48` instruction (since 48 is `'0'`, 49 is `'1'`, 0 is `false` and 1 ia `true`).  The code above collects all of these converted ASCII digits into a mutable `Vec<u8>`.

Why mutable?  There’s a function `sum.reverse()` that reverses the bytes of output in place, with no additional memory allocation or copying.  When you enable vector instructions, the implementation uses them to optimize this step.

Since that gets us the correct UTF-8 output string, we can call `String::from_utf8` to move the buffer directly from the `Vec` container to a `String` container, without needing to make another copy.  Since this returns a `Result` type, we need to `.unwrap()` the return value.  It’s good practice to use `.expect` for this with a debug message. (We could *in theory* use the `unsafe` function `String::from_utf8_unchecked` instead.)

### Putting it All Together

```rust
fn zip_pad<IterA, IterB>(mut left_it: IterA, mut right_it: IterB) ->
    impl Iterator<Item = (IterA::Item, IterB::Item)>
where
    IterA: Iterator,
    IterB: Iterator,
    IterA::Item: Default,
    IterB::Item: Default
{
    return std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        match (left_it.next(), right_it.next()) {
            (None, None)              => None,
            (Some(left), None)        => Some ((left, IterB::Item::default())),
            (None, Some(right))       => Some((IterA::Item::default(), right)),
            (Some(left), Some(right)) => Some((left, right))
        }
    })
}


fn ripple_carry_adder( left_input :&str, right_input: &str ) -> String {
    let a_rev = left_input.bytes()
                          .rev()
                          .map(to_bool);
    let b_rev = right_input.bytes()
                           .rev()
                           .map(to_bool);
    let mut reverse_zip = zip_pad(a_rev, b_rev).peekable();
    let mut carry = false;

    let mut sum : Vec<u8> = std::iter::from_fn(move|| {
        match (reverse_zip.peek(), carry) {
            (None, false) => None,
            (None, true) => {
                carry = false;
                Some(true)
            }
            (Some(&(a, b)), carry_in) => {
                let (digit, carry_out) = add_bits(a, b, carry_in);
                carry = carry_out;
                reverse_zip.next();
                Some(digit)
            }
        }
    }).map(to_utf8)
      .collect();

    /* The output string was generated in reverse order.  Reverse it in place,
     * without copying.
     */
    sum.reverse();

    /* Since the bytes of the vector are valid UTF-8, move them to a string,
     * without copying.
     */
    return String::from_utf8(sum).expect("The output should have contained only two possible values.");

    const fn to_bool(c :u8) -> bool {
        match c as char {
            '0' => false,
            '1' => true,
            _ => unimplemented!()
        }
    }

    const fn add_bits(a: bool, b: bool, c: bool) -> (bool, bool)
    {
        match (a, b, c) {
            (false, false, false) => (false, false),
            (false, false, true)  => (true, false),
            (false, true, false)  => (true, false),
            (false, true, true)   => (false, true),
            (true, false, false)  => (true, false),
            (true, false, true)   => (false, true),
            (true, true, false)   => (false, true),
            (true, true, true)    => (true, true)
        }
    }

    const fn to_utf8(d: bool) -> u8 {
        match d {
            false => '0' as u8,
            true  => '1' as u8
        }
    }
}
```

And a few tests:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let test1 = ripple_carry_adder("101", "1");
    assert!(test1 == "110", "Expected 101 + 1 = 110. Got {}", test1);
    println!("Test 1 passed.");

    let test2 = ripple_carry_adder("1011", "1");
    assert!(test2 == "1100", "Expected 1011 + 1 = 1100. Got {}", test2);
    println!("Test 2 passed.");

    let test3 = ripple_carry_adder("101010", "10101");
    assert!(test3 == "111111", "Expected 101010 + 10101 = 111111. Got {}", test3);
    println!("Test 3 passed.");

    let test4 = ripple_carry_adder("100", "100");
    assert!(test4 == "1000", "Expected 100 + 100 = 1000. Got {}", test4);
    println!("Test 4 passed.");
}
```

[You can try it out on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/57a5rMzPG)

Comment: I had a custom `default` parameter on `zip_longest` because I don't think the default `char` is `'0'`, and I feel like it would be a pain to make a custom type and `Default` for every `zip_longest` call? Is there a way to take iterators while also specifying the underlying values won't be mutated?

Comment: @theonlygusti That’s a valid use case! Here, I just switched to a `bool` representation where padding with the default value sufficed.

Comment: @theonlygusti Are you thinking of the `Cloned` trait, for iterators that clone instead of moving or mutating their data? I don’t think Rust makes it possible to stop a type from also implementing some other trait that enables interior mutability. You could also maybe stick it in a `const fn`, so the compiler will warn you about *some* things that could have externally-visible side-effects.

Comment: @theonlygusti Now that I understand your reasoning—which is valid; sometimes you want to pad with zero digits, sometime spaces, sometimes null bytes—I don’t think there’s a significantly better way than your original approach. You do, in this case, want to `.clone()` the user-supplied padding object. (And maybe call it something like that, instead of `default`, because the two meanings of default confused me.) For a primitive type like `char`, that’s zero-cost. Just pass it by immutable reference?

Comment: I'm still a Rust newbie, so this might not be totally valid, but when I see `(mut left_it:` in the function signature, the `mut` keyword makes me think "okay the function wants to modify some of the values inside of the iterator". Doesn't the `mut` keyword give it permission to do that? Is there a way to take iterable arguments into the function without requiring that permission to mutate be granted?

Comment: @theonlygusti Generally, iterators themselves need to be `mut` in order to call `next` on them (because `.next()` updates the iterator). If you call `.iter()`, the iterators return non-owning references, which sounds like what you want. If you call `.iter_mut()`, you get iterators over mutable references, and `.into_iter()` transfers ownership of the elements. There are also, as I mentioned, iterators that clone instead.